# Implied exchange rate

Tags: fx

The EUR/JPY exchange rate increased by 20%.

The USD/JPY exchange rate increased by 25%.

By how much will the EUR/USD exchange rate decrease?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems pretty basic, assuming no arbitrage: 
$$X^{EUR}_{USD}(t+1) = X^{EUR}_{JPY}(t+1)/X^{USD}_{JPY}(t+1) = (1.2*X^{EUR}_{JPY}(t))/(1.25 * X^{USD}_{JPY}(t)) = 0.96 * X^{EUR}_{JPY}(t)$$
So EUR/USD decreases by 4%.